# change css to support ie 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Here is the thing, the css works really well when I use chrome and shows like the picture.
This is what I want.

[image]

However, when it comes to using IE 11. The result will show like the another picture 
[image]

Here is part of my source code.

Html:

```
<ul style="margin-top: 0px;padding-left: 25px; margin-bottom: 0px;padding-right: 5px;padding-bottom: 5px;padding-top: 0px;">
    <li class = "chineseNumber">
        aaa
    </li>
    <li class = "chineseNumber">
        bbb
        <ul class="customUl">
            <li class="customLi one">
                ccc  
            </li>
            <li class="customLi two">
                ddd 
            </li>
        </ul>   
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.chineseNumber{ 
    list-style-type: cjk-ideographic;
}

ul.customUl{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    counter-reset: none;
}

ul.customUl li.customLi{
    list-style-type: none;
    position:relative;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    padding-left:35px;
    margin-left: -5;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

ul.customUl li.customLi:before{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
ul.customUl li.one:before { 
    content: "（一）"; 
}

ul.customUl li.two:before { 
    content: "（二）"; 
}
```

And demo line:
http://jsfiddle.net/apss1943/JR5Xk/31/

I want the UI in IE version can look like the same with Chrome 
May anyone can help me or gives me some hits to solve the problem in IE 11.

The pic shows what I saw in IE 11.
[image]

Comment: I am using IE11 and am getting the desired output.

Comment: Do you get all Chinese characters?

Comment: I get exactly [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hoE3X.png)

Comment: Do you set any things in IE 11. Otherwise, how can this line work well in IE?Css: list-style-type: cjk-ideographic

Comment: How am I supposed to set something in my browser? I open it and enter the URL and press the Enter!